# How to prevent dot from taking an extremely long time?

Tags: graphviz, dot

When I run Graphviz on a specific graph, I get

```
aromanov@ws:~/IdeaProjects/scalan$ dot -v -O -Tpng myfile.dot 
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times Roman,) (PangoCairoFcFont) "DejaVu Sans 14" 
network simplex:  605 nodes 1434 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=1
network simplex: 100 
network simplex: 605 nodes 1434 edges 131 iter 0.01 sec
mincross: pass 0 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 28683 best_cross 28683
mincross: pass 0 iter 1 trying 0 cur_cross 21867 best_cross 21867
mincross: pass 0 iter 2 trying 0 cur_cross 11534 best_cross 11534
mincross: pass 0 iter 3 trying 0 cur_cross 8949 best_cross 8949
mincross: pass 1 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 8701 best_cross 6900
mincross: pass 1 iter 1 trying 1 cur_cross 14055 best_cross 6900
mincross: pass 1 iter 2 trying 2 cur_cross 11429 best_cross 6900
mincross: pass 1 iter 3 trying 3 cur_cross 7558 best_cross 6900
mincross: pass 2 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 6190 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 1 trying 1 cur_cross 11316 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 2 trying 2 cur_cross 11511 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 3 trying 3 cur_cross 7098 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 4 trying 4 cur_cross 6628 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 5 trying 5 cur_cross 13131 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 6 trying 6 cur_cross 11633 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 7 trying 7 cur_cross 7562 best_cross 6190
mincross: pass 2 iter 8 trying 8 cur_cross 6800 best_cross 6190
merge2: graph G, rank 5 has only 52 < 53 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 9 has only 82 < 83 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 30 has only 123 < 124 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 38 has only 141 < 142 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 42 has only 148 < 149 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 59 has only 172 < 173 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 60 has only 177 < 178 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 61 has only 179 < 180 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 62 has only 185 < 187 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 63 has only 187 < 189 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 64 has only 188 < 190 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 65 has only 186 < 188 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 66 has only 189 < 190 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 74 has only 207 < 208 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 80 has only 222 < 223 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 81 has only 226 < 227 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 82 has only 226 < 227 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 83 has only 228 < 229 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 84 has only 230 < 231 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 85 has only 232 < 233 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 86 has only 232 < 233 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 87 has only 232 < 233 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 88 has only 236 < 237 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 89 has only 239 < 240 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 90 has only 244 < 245 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 91 has only 246 < 247 nodes
merge2: graph G, rank 118 has only 177 < 178 nodes
mincross G: 6189 crossings, 8.40 secs.
network simplex:  57721 nodes 86837 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2
network simplex: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 
network simplex: 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000 
network simplex: 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500 2600 2700 2800 2900 3000 
network simplex: 3100 3200 3300 3400 3500 3600 3700 3800 3900 4000 
network simplex: 4100 4200 4300 4400 4500 4600 4700 4800 4900 5000 
network simplex: 5100 5200 5300 5400 5500 5600 5700 5800 5900 6000
```

And so on. For some reason it is attempting to work with 57721 nodes, when the graph only has 605 nodes (as the beginning of the error says). Is there a way to tell it to stop, perhaps with a worse layout? I've tried other layouts as well; neato and twopi produced a complete mess with everything overlapping, fdp is somewhat better but still very bad, and circo seems to hang as well. Graphviz version is 2.26.3 (which is unfortunately the latest available for Debian stable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We fixed that.  Debian should get the latest release. Version 2.26 is over 4 years old. Try to install it from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php

Note that the number of nodes reported includes the virtual ("dummy") nodes created to route edges across the levels of a ranked graph. You can get quadratic blowup if the graph has a lot of "long" edges. This is not a bug.

For 605 nodes, I'd suggest neato -Goverlap=false  or -Elen=2 or 3  or sfdp (it ignores edge lengths but seems better at avoiding overlaps).

With |E| ~= 3|V|  your graph is not necessarily too dense or difficult to lay out.

Stephen North

Comment: Unfortunately, 2.38.0 package at that page requires libc6 >= 2.15. Do you happen to know which is the latest version which will work with 2.13 (and if it's available for download from somewhere)?